# Contact form from ubuntu to Zoho email address

Tags: ubuntu, php, postfix, html, smtp-auth

I would like some support in order to get my Postfix configuration working with my Zoho email account. What I am trying to do is to send a message from my contact form in http://www.g3eo.com/#!/page_Contacts to my Zoho email account. For that I configured Postfix in my ubuntu box in this way (based on http://emanuelesantanche.com/configuring-postfix-to-relay-email-through-zoho-mail/):

> smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
>       biff = no
>
> ```
> append_dot_mydomain = no
>
> readme_directory = no
>
> mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
> mailbox_size_limit = 0
> recipient_delimiter = +
> inet_interfaces = loopback-only
> inet_protocols = all
>
> # TLS parameters
> smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
> smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
> smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
> smtpd_use_tls=yes
> smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
> smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
> smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
>
> myhostname = xxxxxxxxxx
> alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
> alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
> mydestination = xxxxxxxxxx, localhost.com, localhost
> relayhost = smtp.zoho.com:587
> smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
> smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/password
> #smtp_sasl_security_options =
> smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
> smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
> smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
> smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
> ```

In my website contact form things seem to be working fine, you can test it by sending a message with the Firebug open (press F12) in the Network tab. After sending the email it appears this message "mail sent" in the response tab. However, that message does not reach my email address in my Zoho email account. After checking the `/var/log/mail.log` it shows:

> Jul 4 21:46:42 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[9100]: D9B2E5E0292:
>   from=, size=549, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul 4 21:46:45 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/smtp[27824]: D9B2E5E0292: to=, relay=smtp.zoho.com[165.254.168.48]:587, delay=114224,
>   delays=114222/0.01/2.6/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; server smtp.zoho.com[165.254.168.48] said: 535 Authentication Failed)

I understand that the authentication problem is because my message could get into the Zoho smtp server, so it was rejected, not sure if it is the case. I would appreciate if someone could help to understand what is going on here and how to fix it.

My contact form uses the following files:
- http://www.g3eo.com/extras/js/forms.js

and http://www.g3eo.com/extras/bin/MailHandler.php (see below)

> ```
>   if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
>       $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
>       $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
>   }
>   if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
>       $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
>       $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
>   }else{
>       $headers = '';
>   }
>   if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
>       $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
>       $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
>   }
>   if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
>       $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
>       $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
>   }   
>   if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
>       $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
>       $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
>   }
>   if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
>       $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
>   }
>
>   if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
>       $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
>   }
>
>   try{
>       if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
>           throw new Exception('mail failed');
>       }else{
>           echo 'mail sent';
>       }
>   }catch(Exception $e){
>       echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
>   }
> ```

**EDIT#1:**

after changing `/etc/postfix/password` from `smtp.zoho.com:587` to `[smtp.zoho.com]` I receiced in `/var/log/mail.log`:

> Jul 4 23:46:24 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/pickup[2926]: 8BC545E0261:
>   uid=33 from=
>        Jul 4 23:46:24 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/cleanup[2933]: 8BC545E0261:
>   message-id=<20160705044624.8BC545E0261@xxxxxxxxxx>
>
> Jul 4 23:46:24 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[2927]: 8BC545E0261:
>   from=, size=588, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul 4 23:46:26 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/smtp[2930]: 8BC545E0261:
>   to=, relay=smtp.zoho.com[165.254.168.48]:587,
>   delay=2.1, delays=0.13/0/1.8/0.16, dsn=5.5.1, status=bounced (host
>   smtp.zoho.com[165.254.168.48] said: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>   (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
>
> Jul 4 23:46:27 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/cleanup[2933]: 098835E026E:
>   message-id=<20160705044627.098835E026E@xxxxxxxxxx>
>
> Jul 4 23:46:27 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/bounce[2932]: 8BC545E0261:
>   sender non-delivery notification: 098835E026E
>
> Jul 4 23:46:27 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[2927]: 098835E026E:
>   from=<>, size=2494, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jul 4 23:46:27 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[2927]: 8BC545E0261:
>   removed
>
> Jul 4 23:46:27 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/local[2934]: 098835E026E:
>   to=, relay=local, delay=0.09,
>   delays=0.05/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Jul 4 23:46:27 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[2927]: 098835E026E:
>   removed

is `587` the problem here?

Comment: Isn't it just rejecting your authentication?

Comment: not really sure but it could be, how can I fix that?

Comment: Check `/etc/postfix/password` to make sure it contains `[smtp.zoho.com] yourusername:yourpassword`, that you ran `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/passwords` and restarted the `postfix` service.

Comment: thanks already did it but the message does not reach my email account yet, please take a look at my first edit (EDIT#1), is the `587` the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!, here the solution:

I had in `/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks`:

```
/^From:.*/ REPLACE From: LOCALHOST System <info@g3eo.com>;
```

and now I have:

```
/^From:.*/ REPLACE From:info@g3eo.com
```

check that I had to delete the semi-colon at the end as well as the whole "LOCALHOST SYTEM" plus blank spaces, and that was it!! hope this helps someone else out there, cheers!